# How to get a dropdown on the nav using twitter bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get a dropdown to work using twitter bootstrap in the nav but am having trouble.  When I click on "More...", nothing shows up.

Any advice?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
    <script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.js"></script>   

    <script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>

    <link href="bootstrap1.css" rel="stylesheet">



  </head>


<body>
    <!-- Navbar
    ================================================== -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>
           <a class="brand" href="/">Name</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse">


            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active">
                <a href="/">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="">
                <a href="/browse">Browse</a>
              </li>
              <li class="">
                <a href="/about">About</a>
              </li>

              <li class="">
                <a href="/faq">FAQ</a>
              </li>

              <li>
                <a href="http://submeup.tumblr.com/">Blog</a>
              </li>

              <li class="">
                <a href="/contactinfo">Contact</a>
              </li>


              <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">More...  </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
                        <li>First</li>
                        <li>First</li>
                        <li>First</li>
                        <li>First</li>
                    </ul>
              </li>


            </ul>


                    <ul class="nav pull-right">
                    <li><a href="/accounts/register/">Sign up</a></li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li><a href="/accounts/login/">Login</a></li>
                </ul>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the latest version of bootstrap and it seems to be working now.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `role="menu"` to `<ul class="dropdown-menu" >`

Comment: No, this doesn't seem to do anything.